# How to install LaTeX the right way from the start

Tags: software-installation, latex

As a quick background to the question, years ago I installed LaTeX on a Linux Mint computer just using the package manager.  Worked for a long time.  Then I needed to install a package that `tlmgr` couldn't find. When I asked a question on StackExchange about how to do this, the only response was "Your installation is weird."

I believe the issue was that the package manager doesn't create a texmf tree structure when it installs.  I later tried to create a tree structure and failed, and just gave up.

Then years after that, re-installed LaTeX.  I think the new install has somehow come into conflict with the old installation.  So now I want to just utterly uninstall and wipe all LaTeX installations off of my computer and install it the right way from the start.

The problem is that every instruction I find on how to install LaTeX says to do it from the package manager, which is what got me in trouble the first time.

So the question: I have utterly purged all earlier installations of LaTeX from my machine, as far as I can tell.  (entering `which latex` returns nothing at the command line)  I know I want to install LaTeX in such a way that it is configured to have a texmf tree and can install packages outside of the package manager.  What's the right way to do it?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, however there's some possibly related information here: [tlmgr in Ubuntu 20.04: “Local TeX Live (2019) is older than remote repository (2020)” (and subsequent issues)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540429/tlmgr-in-ubuntu-20-04-local-tex-live-2019-is-older-than-remote-repository-2)

Comment: I would ignore linux packages and install vanilla texlive from https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html Advantages: you'll be able to access updated package with only 1 day delay instead of months or years as for some linux packages and b) if you do a complete install, you'll basically never again have to worry about missing packages. If disk space is not a problem, just make sure that the vanilla texlive is found earlier in your path then the linux texlive and leave that one alone. If space is an issue, there are dummy packages that can be used to replace linux texlive.